# iOS 8.3 - Metal, found nil while unwrapping an Optional Value

Tags: ios, metal

Before Apple released iOS 8.3 my code worked, however since the updating XCode complains that a nil value is found, even though none of my values are nil (I validated this when debugging).

For sanity, I re-wrote my program to render a simple triangle to the screen with Metal, but the same error is thrown.  I have an array of 3 vertices, I then multiply that by the array size to get the size of the buffer and pass in `OptionCPUCacheModeDefault` as I thought passing a `nil` parameter may have been what was causing my problem.

```
// Test array of vertices
let ASVertices:[Float] = [
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
    -1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, -1.0, 0.0
]

// Other Metal init code...

// Set the buffers
let dataSize = ASVertices.count * sizeofValue(ASVertices[0])
vertexBuffer = ASDevice.newBufferWithBytes(ASVertices, 
                              length: dataSize, 
                              options: MTLResourceOptions.OptionCPUCacheModeDefault)
```

When I debug, I can see that `dataSize` is 36 (9*4) as expected, so I am fairly stumped as to why I am getting a `fatal error when unwrapping an optional value`.  I know that error is self explanatory but the code printed above is where the stack trace shows the exception being raised, but I see no nil values there.  What could be causing this?

Comment: An unrelated comment, `ASVertices` should be `asVertices` - by convention variables start with a lowercase letter.  Classes & types start with a capital.  A for the actual cause of your crash, have you tried single-stepping to see where the failure occurs?  Swift is notorius for giving misleading exception locations

Comment: No, just vertices. AS is a prefix, which is not Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Metal doesn't really work with iOS 8.3, when connected to Xcode. For now, disable GPU Frame Capture, and file a radar.