# iOS 8.3 Metal halt and crash

Tags: ios, xcode, metal

After upgrading to iOS 8.3 SDK in Xcode and on device. My applications involved metal are not working properly. Metal are used for obj file visualization and for GPU computing. My applications halt for several seconds then crashed. I noticed that in Xcode console shows "Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled", which doesn't appear before. Is this caused problem? If so is there anyway to turn off this functionality in iOS 8.3?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29584463/ios-8-3-metal-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-value

Comment: Does this mean this issue has not been solved by Apple?

Comment: If they solved it, we haven't been given the build with the solution yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless not connected to Xcode, I haven't been able to run any Metal apps, with GPU frame capture turned on, with iOS 8.3. Here's how you disable it:

[image: How to disable GPU Frame Capture]

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Dev-Technique/Dev-Technique.html